# Laravel: How can a middleware be added to a named route?

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

Laravel: How can a middleware be added to a named route?

If the middleware has been created and registered in kernel.php, how can middleware be added to the following route?:

`Route::post('/segment/{param}/segment','SomeController@index')->name('post');`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `middleware()` method

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

```
Route::post('/segment/{param}/segment','SomeController@index')
     ->name('post')
     ->middleware('middleware_name');
```

Comment: This works when the `->middleware('middleware_name');` is set to the key chosen in `kernel.php` under 'protected $routeMiddleware = [ ];`